# AutoCompleteTextField controller not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a problem, I have a autocompletetextfield its work fine but contoller not working when i settext throw controller nothing happen, others work fine (quantity and price controllers)...

Examples:

[On search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvuz.png) [itemSubmit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct3BP.png)

here is my TextField

```
AutoCompleteTextField<Services>(
                    controller: _serviceController,
                    itemSorter: (Services a, Services b) {
                      return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      labelText: "Service",
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Light",
                    ),
                    suggestions: Services.list,
                    itemFilter: (Services suggestion, String query) {
                      return suggestion.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                    },

                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, Services suggestion) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(suggestion.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    key: null,

                    itemSubmitted: (Services data) {
                      setState(() {
                        **_serviceController.text = data.name;**
                        _priceController.text = data.price;
                        _quantityController.text = data.quantity.toString();
                      });
                    },

                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give **Key**, just assign a GlobalKey to AutoCompleteTextField Widget

```
GlobalKey key = new GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<Services>>();

AutoCompleteTextField<Services>(
                    controller: _serviceController,
                    itemSorter: (Services a, Services b) {
                      return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      labelText: "Service",
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Light",
                    ),
                    suggestions: Services.list,
                    itemFilter: (Services suggestion, String query) {
                      return suggestion.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                    },

                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, Services suggestion) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(suggestion.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    key: key,

                    itemSubmitted: (Services data) {
                      setState(() {
                        _serviceController.text = data.name;
                        _priceController.text = data.price;
                        _quantityController.text = data.quantity.toString();
                      });
                    },

                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my problem was AutoCompleteTextField have a field named ClearOnSubmit, by default its true so I make it false and now my code working perfect.